# Executing a bat. file with arguments from vba code

Tags: vba, terminal

I'm trying to execute a bat. file from vba but can't get it working (after viewing some of the threads from the subject).

here is the code now:

```
Dim filet As String
Dim numero As String

Const pekka = "TIEDOSTO"
Const sami = "NUMEROT"
filet = Range(pekka).Cells(1, 1).value
numero = Range(sami).Cells(1, 1).value

commandstring = "D:"
commandstring2 = "cd folder name"
commandstring3 = "Create-tri.bat" + " " + filet + " " + numero
Call Shell("cmd.exe /S" & commandstring & commandstring2 & commandstring3, vbNormalFocus)
```

So according to my logic, this code should first access D, then the wanted folder and then execute the bat. file with the given parameters (filet and numero). What am I doing wrong here?

Best regards and thanks in advance,

Johannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the `Call`, it is depreciated in VBA.

Then use `Shell "cmd.exe /S" & commandstring & commandstring2 & commandstring3`.

To see what you are actually trying to execute, use:

`Debug.Print "cmd.exe /S" & commandstring & commandstring2 & commandstring3`

What do you get? Most probably it is not an executable command, ending on `.bat` Some reference here - [Execute .bat file from Excel VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530371/execute-bat-file-from-excel-vba-macro)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Hmm, after editing the code according to your instructions the debug.print looks pretty much as the code which I would normally manually write to the terminal. The problem is that the shell command doesn't actually seem to print anything to the terminal itself. It just opens it.

Comment: @JohannesJuolahti - I am not sure what the `/S` does, probably you may try with `/k` as in the accepted answer.